# Convert excel format to C# TimeStamp like excel do so

Tags: c#, excel

In my app I'm reading some data from excel sheet and i stucked in the moment when i want to get timestamp from a cell. In this speciffic cell i got a value '1900-01-02  13:20:04' and in excel i am using format '[h]:mm:ss' which formats this value to '61:20:04', which is correct beacuse those cells are showing hours worked by some employees.
What I want to achieve is to read this data from excel in the same format as it's formated in excel('61:20:04') and save it to string. My problem is how to read this, or convert to this timestamp value ?

EDIT.(the way i am doing it now)

I am reading the code from excel using ODBC so just select data i need(like sQl select) -> add all data to datatable and then i'm just doing

dr["workedHours"].ToString() -(dr = DataRow in my DataTable.Rows) this line returns '1900-01-02  13:20:04'. How can I convert it to time like excel does.

Comment: What about telling us how you did the data-reading until now? E.g. showing some code.

Comment: I've editted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some proof of concept:

```
var timeStamp = "1900-01-02 13:20:04";
var date = DateTime.Parse(timeStamp);
var stamp = date.Subtract(new DateTime(1900, 1, 1));
var result = string.Format("{0}:{1:00}:{2:00}", 24 + stamp.Days * 24 + stamp.Hours, stamp.Minutes, stamp.Seconds);
```

It seems for some reason Excel takes time stamps from 0 January 1900, this is why I add 24 in hours result.

I assumed you always want format hh:mm:ss, even for days, month, etc.

Comment: Yupp, this code works. Its quite same method as C4ud3x's but without this one little mistake. Marked as answer cause this one is more complete. Thanks for both of you(i would like to mark both as answers)

Comment: Nah. This one is the more accurate one as using the converting methods of dateTime. Giving an upvote.

Comment: You're right. Your(C4ud3x) code 'without minus one' worked fine but i had to format it using string.format.
This code work without formatting. Great job - thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Without any code provided Ill go away from 'how to read data the right way' and point to 'how to convert your output'.

Could work like this:

```
string[] stampParts = output.ToString().Split(' ');
string[] dateParts = stampParts[0].Split('-');
string[] timeParts = stampParts[1].Split(':');

var result = new TimeSpan(((Convert.ToInt32(dateParts[2])-1)*24) + Convert.ToInt32(timeParts[0]), Convert.ToInt32(timeParts[1]), Convert.ToInt32(timeParts[2]));
```

This would add the days from the date with 24 hours by a single one to the hours of your time.
**Notice:** I left out calculating the months here. So this code is limited in calculation up one month. If you want to output larger numbers (over about 720 hours) the months have to be included into the calculation.

**Edit after code was provided:**
Sorry, I havnt worked with odbc-connections before. But the point is: You are getting the raw-value instead of the calculated one. I already tried googling for that, but couldnt find much results.

Maybe someone else can help out with this. Instead I would suggest just converting the output.

Comment: I didn't provide code cause i wanted a right method to do it just like your code. Some abstract code no need to be speciffic.
I tried something your code already but it gives me 1.13:20:04. One day = 24H so sum of this one day and time gives me about 37H. In excel I see 64 hours. I have no idea how excel counts it.

Comment: As I said: Maybe there's a way to get the calculated value out of the excel-doc. I wasnt able to find something useful with google so far. The point where I can help is already posted. // I saw your edit. Let me check my code for myself. Give me some minutes.

Comment: Man your CODE is PERFECT. Just no need to use minus one in (Convert.ToInt32(dateParts[2])-1)*24)
(because second day means two days and 13 hours not 13th our of second day)

Comment: What? If I remove the '-1' it gives me output: 2.13:20:04. !?

Comment: it means 2 days so 2 days x 24 = 48 + 13,20 = 61:20 just like in excel and then i just formatted in using string.format. I'll Paste the code in a few minutes as an edit.

Comment: Ah yeah. I got it. With string.format it will work. Ty for getting this clear.